# Convert PHP regex into VB.Net Regex

Tags: php, regex, vb.net, match, converters

I am trying to convert a regex from PHP to VB.Net. Does anyone know of a software utility, or conversion chart to do so? The regex is the following: `name=\"?(.*?)\"? value=\"(.*?)\"`. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escpae double-quotes in VB by doubling the double-quotes(`""`):

Your regex would be

```
 name=""?(.*?)""? value=""(.*?)""
```

Comment: So two quotes count as one?